# Should one hide RTL encoded URLs in robots.txt or not?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a MediaWiki 1.32.0 RTL site (Hebrew) and I desire to hide some of its URLs from search engines like Google and Bing by `robots.txt`.

The `robots.txt` command `Disallow: /מדיה_ויקי:*` can have two **UTF-8** versions for RTL languages (Hebrew in this case); one is decoded and one is encoded;

Decoded:

```
Disallow: /מדיה_ויקי:*
```

Encoded:

```
Disallow: /%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99:*
```

Both are same in essence - disabling indexation of everything that starts with `מדיה-ויקי:`.

**Which one should I put in robots.txt?**

Comment: I suggest you to test both solutions with the https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124458/is-it-problematic-to-include-both-decoded-and-encoded-versions-of-the-same-direc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is pushing to standardize `robots.txt` syntax because it was never standardized in fact; ([see their announcement](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/07/rep-id.html)); this is happening right now at the IETF with [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koster-rep-00).

Google help page already references it, so I guess we can safely use it as a formal specification.

The draft includes this relevant grammar (keeping only the parts useful in our case):

```
rule = *WS ("allow" / "disallow") *WS ":"
       *WS (path-pattern / empty-pattern) EOL

path-pattern = "/" *(UTF8-char-noctl) ; valid URI path pattern

; UTF8 derived from RFC3629, but excluding control characters

UTF8-char-noctl = UTF8-1-noctl / UTF8-2 / UTF8-3 / UTF8-4
UTF8-1-noctl = %x21 / %x22 / %x24-7F ; excluding control, space, '#'
UTF8-2 = %xC2-DF UTF8-tail
UTF8-3 = %xE0 %xA0-BF UTF8-tail / %xE1-EC 2( UTF8-tail ) /
         %xED %x80-9F UTF8-tail / %xEE-EF 2( UTF8-tail )
UTF8-4 = %xF0 %x90-BF 2( UTF8-tail ) / %xF1-F3 3( UTF8-tail ) /
         %xF4 %x80-8F 2( UTF8-tail )

UTF8-tail = %x80-BF
```

So, in short, while you can use UTF-8, it has to be encoded, per RFC3986.

This is spelled out again later in the document:

> Octets in the URI and robots.txt paths outside the range of the US-
> ASCII coded character set, and those in the reserved range defined by
> RFC3986 [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), MUST be percent-encoded as defined by RFC3986 [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) prior
> to comparison.

Hence, I believe that you should use your second form:

```
Disallow: /%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99:*
```

Regarding `:*`, `*` should be percent encoded only if you want to specifically match this character, but if you need its "glob" behavior of matching anything, [you need to keep it as is](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

Comment: Another humble edit suggestion: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62733

Comment: @JohnDoea Thanks, applied with my minor changes.

Comment: Dear Patrick, you might want to answer here as well: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124458/is-it-problematic-to-include-both-decoded-and-encoded-versions-of-the-same-direc

Comment: @JohnDoea sorry but I do not understand why. My answer here says: you need to do X, based on some reference. Your new question is now: can I do X and Y at the same time? I think it is already answered by this very own reply.