# Is it problematic to include both decoded and encoded versions of the same directives in robots.txt?

Tags: url, web-crawlers, robots.txt, url-encoding

This question is a follow up to this one:
[Should one hide RTL encoded URLs in robots.txt or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124194/should-one-hide-rtl-encoded-urls-in-robots-txt-or-not)

Is it problematic to include both decoded and encoded versions of the same directives in `robots.txt`, such as the following?

```
Disallow: /מדיה_ויקי:*
Disallow: /%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99:*
```

<sub>Both are actually "the same" in the sense that the first one is in its original RTL syntax (Hebrew, in this case) and decoded and the second one is encoded.</sub>

The "rationale" is to "aim" at **any** current or possible-in-future standard from Google (or any other major search engine for that matter).
For example:
Today one major search engine development team might prefer decoded versions and tomorrow another might prefer the encoded version;
Hence the question if it's okay to just have both and be done with it?

Comment: I think this is already answered by (my own answer) at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/124210/75842. The specification says you need to "%-encode" things in the file. You can not envision everything the future will bring and do things defensively regarding that. So for me, right now, based on the specifications, doing anything else than %-encoding is wrong.

Comment: Hello ! I think "you cannot" should have been "I think you shouldn't" ^__^ Thanks !

Comment: Is @JohnDoea and @[JosephElazar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124194/should-one-hide-rtl-encoded-urls-in-robots-txt-or-not) (from the linked question) the same person?

Comment: Maybe so, this is for another discussion in meta I believe;

Comment: @PatrickMevzek by `%-encoding` do you mean to `UTF-8` encoding or something else? I feel confused regarding this...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek please consider adding a clarification on this to your answer there (I read the answer twice and don't recall it was clear to me that by `%-encoding` you meant `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether the [proposed *draft* standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koster-rep-00) specifies that you should encode or not, to answer your specific question...

No, it is unlikely to cause a problem if you include both URL encoded (%-encoded) and URL decoded (%-decoded) URLs in `robots.txt`. One or other will simply get ignored, as one or other simply won't match.

**UPDATE:** To clarify, everything (ie. the entire `robots.txt` file) should be UTF-8 encoded. This is simply the character encoding of the file. So, both the "URL encoded" and "URL decoded" URLs in `robots.txt` are in fact UTF-8 encoded. "UTF-8 encoded" and "URL encoded" refer to different things. I'd previously used the phrase "*standard* UTF-8 encoded" to differentiate from "URL encoded" - this was perhaps misleading, as both are "UTF-8 encoded". Google's webmaster guidelines (quoted below) uses the terms "UTF-8 characters" and "percent-escaped UTF-8 encoded characters" to differentiate the two.

Rather confusingly, [Google's robots.txt tester tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) only appears to match against %-decoded URLs<sup>***1**</sup>. But, as far as I've been able to determine, this is an (surprising<sup>***2**</sup>) inconsistency in the tool only and not reflected in the real Googlebot. Reference: https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/search-console-robots-txt-tester-inconsistencies/

<sup>(***1** It looks like the tool *blindly* URL encodes the URL before comparison?)</sup>
<sup>(***2** If this really is a bug in the tool, why hasn't Google addressed this issue in the last 3+ years?)</sup>

FWIW, the [Google Webmaster help guidelines regarding `robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt), which states that it has been updated to reflect the [proposed Internet standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koster-rep-00) (1-July-2019) appears to suggest that whether you %-encode the URL or not is *optional*:

> Non-7-bit ASCII characters in a path *may be included as UTF-8 characters **or** as percent-escaped UTF-8 encoded characters* per [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

And the [Robots Exclusion Protocol - draft standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koster-rep-00) states:

> [Octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) in the URI and robots.txt paths outside the range of the US-
> ASCII coded character set, and those in the reserved range defined by
> RFC3986, MUST be percent-encoded as defined by RFC3986 **prior
> to comparison**.

Note the last phrase, "prior to comparison" - this is an instruction for implementers of the proposed standard, not necessarily for those writing the `robots.txt` file itself.

---

> ```
> Disallow: /מדיה_ויקי:*
> Disallow: /%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99:*
> ```

*Aside:* You don't need the *wildcard* `*` at the end of the URL, since `robots.txt` is prefix matching by default.

Comment: "both include many percentage signs, don't they?" - No, the UTF-8 encoded string is the "decoded version" as stated in your question. `robots.txt` files (the whole file) should be UTF-8 encoded (character encoding), as opposed to some other language specific encoding, such as Western-1250 (Central European languages), ISO-8859-1 (Western Europe) or ISO 8859-8 (Hebrew), etc.

Comment: "to disallow all webpages of a site one does have to use `Disallow /*`" - No, you only need `Disallow: /` (and don't forget the colon). The _wildcard_ `*` is a later addition to the [original `robots.txt` "standard"](https://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). It is prefix-matching by default, eg. `Disallow: /foo` will disallow `/foo`, `/foobar` and `/foobar/baz/anything.html`, etc. You only _need_ to use `*` if you have a variable part in the _middle_ of the URL.

Comment: Thanks; I must say - I go through a hard period and this topic is extremely confusing and annoying for me. I think this is the first time I hear on "0-7 bit ASCII" VS "full 8 bit UTF-8"; as far as I understand I can indeed combine decoded Hebrew + UTF-8 encoded Hebrew and it should be fine even though encoded UTF-8 Hebrew by itself should be enough.

Comment: BTW, should I define this entire topic "machine-encoding-for-natural-languages" or something else?

Comment: "combine decoded Hebrew + UTF-8 encoded Hebrew and it should be fine even though encoded UTF-8 Hebrew" - I think some of the confusion here is that you are perhaps seeing the terms "UTF-8 encoded" and "URL encoded" to define two different encodings. However, that is not the case. These are unrelated - both are (or should be) in fact UTF-8 encoded. Everything here is UTF-8 encoded - the whole file is UTF-8 encoded - this is the _character encoding_. Whereas "URL encoded" refers only to the URL, where octets are converted to the form `%nn`.

Comment: So, to be verbose, it would be "UTF-8 encoded + URL encoded (ie. %-encoded)" vs "UTF-8 encoded + URL decoded (ie. %-decoded)". Or just remove the term "UTF-8 encoded" completely, as that is _assumed_ here. (`robots.txt` files should always be UTF-8 encoded, as opposed to any other character encoding.) I'll try and clarify this in my answer.

Comment: `should I define this entire topic "machine-encoding-for-natural-languages"` - I suppose you could. (?)

Comment: Thank you so much; yes, a clarification in answer would help me as I plan to re-read the answer.